# How to handle large in-memory data in Apache Beam Pipeline to run on Google Dataflow Runner

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm having a simple following code. The size of the variable `word_to_id` in memory is ~50MB. This causing error in submitting pipeline to Dataflow Runner.

> 413 Request Entity Too Large

```
  word_to_id = {tok: idx for idx, tok in enumerate(vocab)}

  def extract_word_ids(tokens):
    return [word_to_id[w] for w in tokens if word_to_id.get(w, None)]

  with beam.pipeline.Pipeline(
    options=get_pipeline_option()) as p:
    lines = p | 'Read' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(path)

    word_ids = (
        lines
        | 'TokenizeLines' >> beam.Map(words)
        | 'IntergerizeTokens' >> beam.Map(extract_word_ids)
    )
```

Please provide me an alternate solution for this.

Comment: have you checked this? https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#job_messages JSON payload cannot exceed 20Mb

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. How to solve this? How to reduce the size of payload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I'm managed to solve it and it worked. I used `DoFn.setup` to initialize my variable from GCS bucket.

```
class IntergerizeTokens(beam.DoFn):
  """Beam line processing function."""

  def __init__(self, vocab_filename):
    self.vocab_filename = vocab_filename

  def setup(self):
    with tf.io.gfile.GFile(tf.io.gfile.glob(self.vocab_filename + '*')[0], 'r') as fh:
      # read from GCS bucket
    self.word_to_id = {tok: idx for idx, tok in enumerate(vocab)}
    print('Setup done!')

  def process(self, tokens):
    """Takes a lines and yield a list of (token, 1) tuples."""
    return [[self.word_to_id[w] for w in tokens if self.word_to_id.get(w, None)]]
```

> Now pass the `DoFn` in `ParDo`

```
  with beam.pipeline.Pipeline(
    options=get_pipeline_option()) as p:
    lines = p | 'Read' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(path)

    word_ids = (
        lines
        | 'TokenizeLines' >> beam.Map(words)
        | 'IntergerizeTokens' >> beam.ParDo(IntergerizeTokens(vocab_temp_path))
    )
```

This is one way to solve it. I think `DoFn.setup` is good for initializing large variables in memory.

Answer (score 2):

You can use GCS buckets as sources for both the text and the variable and use the variable as `side input`. You can use this side inputs as list, dict or singleton.

Here you have an example of a ***wordcount*** removing the stopwords, which are stored in a GCS bucket

```
with beam.Pipeline() as p:

    path = "gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt"
    stopwords_path = "<BUCKET/stopwords>"

    output_path = "<BUCKET>"

    def split_words(text, stopwords):
            words = re.split('\W+', text)
            try:
                words.remove('')
            except:
                pass
            return [x for x in words if x.lower() not in stopwords]

    stopwords_p = (p | "Read Stop Words" >> ReadFromText(stopwords_path)
                     | FlatMap(lambda x: x.split(", "))) 

    text = p | "Read Text" >> ReadFromText(path)

    (text | "Split Words" >> FlatMap(split_words, stopwords=beam.pvalue.AsList(stopwords_p))
          | "Count" >> Count.PerElement()
          | "Write" >> WriteToText(file_path_prefix=output_path, file_name_suffix=".txt"))
```

Comment: Side input does have size limitation too?